# How to create view with concatenated list and only unique rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SSMS 18 I am trying to create a view that joins three tables.

```
[Client_Info]
+----------+-----------+------------+
| ClientID |  LastName | FirstName  |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|    1     | Smith     | John       |
|    2     | Doe       | Jane       |

[Products_Ordered]
+----------+-------------+
| ClientID |  ProductID  |
+----------+-------------+
|    1     |     111     |
|    1     |     222     |
|    2     |     111     |

[Product_Info] 
+-----------+--------------+
| ProductID |  ProductName |
+-----------+--------------+
|    111    |    Apples    |
|    222    |    Oranges   |
```

I want to end up with the following output, where the products are concatenated into a list for each client.

```
+----------+-----------+------------+------------------+
| ClientID |  LastName | FirstName  |     Products     |
+----------+-----------+------------+------------------+
|    1     | Smith     | John       | Apples, Oranges  |
|    2     | Doe       | Jane       | Apples           |
```

So far, this is what I have

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[uvw_summary]
AS
SELECT A.[ClientID]  
         , A.[LASTNAME]                                           
        , A.[FIRSTNAME]                                          
        ,            (
                     SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), C.[ProductName]) + ', '
                     FROM  [Products_Ordered] AS B 
                                         JOIN [Product_Info] AS C 
                                         ON B.[ProductID] = C.[ProductID]
                     WHERE   A.[ClientID]  = B.[ClientID]
                     ORDER BY B.[ProductID] 
                     FOR XML PATH ('')
              ) AS [Products]
FROM     [Client_Info] AS A 
                     JOIN [Products_Ordered] AS B 
                     ON  A.[ClientID] = B.[ClientID]
                     JOIN [Product_Info] AS C 
                     ON B.[ProductID] = C.[ProductID]
```

With the existing code, I get two rows per client when they have more than one order.

```
+----------+-----------+------------+------------------+
| ClientID |  LastName | FirstName  |     Products     |
+----------+-----------+------------+------------------+
|    1     | Smith     | John       | Apples, Oranges  |
|    1     | Smith     | John       | Apples, Oranges  |
|    2     | Doe       | Jane       | Apples           |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the joins in the outer query, they are redundant:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[uvw_summary]
AS
SELECT   A.[ClientID]  
       , A.[LASTNAME]                                           
       , A.[FIRSTNAME]                                          
       , (    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), C.[ProductName]) + ', '
              FROM   [Products_Ordered] AS B 
                     JOIN [Product_Info] AS C 
                         ON B.[ProductID] = C.[ProductID]
              WHERE   A.[ClientID]  = B.[ClientID]
              ORDER BY B.[ProductID] 
              FOR XML PATH ('')
         ) AS [Products]
FROM     [Client_Info] AS A;
```

It is also probably worth using `TYPE` along with `.value()` so that you don't get issues when your string contains special XML characters

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[uvw_summary]
AS
SELECT   A.[ClientID]  
       , A.[LASTNAME]                                           
       , A.[FIRSTNAME]                                          
       , (    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), C.[ProductName]) + ', '
              FROM   [Products_Ordered] AS B 
                     JOIN [Product_Info] AS C 
                         ON B.[ProductID] = C.[ProductID]
              WHERE   A.[ClientID]  = B.[ClientID]
              ORDER BY B.[ProductID] 
              FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
         ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Products]
FROM     [Client_Info] AS A;
```

Finally, you say you are using SSMS 18, which doesn't really mean much as SSMS is a user interface, and doesn't tell us anything about the version of SQL Server you are using, but if you are using a more recent version of SSMS, then you might be using a more recent version of SQL Server, if you are, you can use `STRING_AGG`:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[uvw_summary]
AS
SELECT  A.[ClientID]  
      , A.[LASTNAME]                                           
      , A.[FIRSTNAME]                                          
      , STRING_AGG(C.[ProductName], ',') WITHIN GROUP ORDER BY c.ProductName)
FROM    [Client_Info] AS A
        JOIN [Products_Ordered] AS B 
            ON A.[ClientID] = B.[ClientID]
        JOIN [Product_Info] AS C 
            ON B.[ProductID] = C.[ProductID]
GROUP BY a.[ClientID], A.[LASTNAME], A.[FIRSTNAME];
```